# how to insert a text into particular location in pdf?

Tags: python, pdf, geospatial

I have a geo Spatial Pdf in which coordinates data is encoded and i have UTM X and UTM Y available and i want to insert a text 'Hello world' at that location but i don,t know how to do it. I tried using different python libraries but don,t know how to do it. Can you guide how to solve this issue becuase i know i can insert text at particular pixels of pdf using this code which i tried . **Please** Can you help me to solve this issue. I will be very thankful to you.

```
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

input_pdf = PdfReader(open('geo.pdf', 'rb'))

buffer = io.BytesIO()
c = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
c.drawString(165.546086513, 490.0217355398, "Hello, World!")
c.save()
buffer.seek(0)


text_pdf = PdfReader(buffer)

output_pdf = PdfWriter()
for i in range(len(input_pdf.pages)):
    page = input_pdf.pages[i]
    if i == 0:
        page.merge_page(text_pdf.pages[0])
    output_pdf.add_page(page)

with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    output_pdf.write(f)
```

Comment: @KJ Sir I believe you are correct but i am not very technical person and i saw the answer below which is not what i want please can you explain me in a simple way or in answer so i can understand it well and this will help me a lot to solve this problem. I will be thankful to you for this favor.

Comment: @KJ Thank you for sharing so much useful information.

Answer (score 1):

A PyMuPDF solution:

```py
import fitz  # import PyMuPDF
filename = 'geo.pdf'
doc = fitz.open(filename)  # open PDF with PyMuPDF

# you need to know which page to write to, example: first page
page = doc[0]

point = fitz.Point(165.546086513, 490.0217355398)  # insertion start point
page.insert_text(point, "Hello, World!")  # insert the text
doc.save("output.pdf")  # save to new file
```

You can select different fonts, fontsizes, text color and what not.
Instead of saving to a new file, you can also modify the existing one:
Repleace last statement `doc.save(...)` by `doc.saveIncr()`.

Comment: Sir please give me way to place text at geo graphical coordinates not on pixels as i already know how to place text on pixels or please refer me a resource where i can find my solution.

Comment: How can I extract the position of a particular cell in a PDF using this library. The thing is I might not always know beforehand, which cell location it is going to be.